# Annotate with an arrow in one facet for a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, annotations

I want to annotate the black dashed line with an arrow and the text "training". But the annotate function annotates all the facets. I just want the arrow in the "remembered/cen" facet only.

Here's my dataset:

```
data10 <- structure(list(Group = c("Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered"), Condition = c("CEN", 
"CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", 
"CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", 
"IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", 
"IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", 
"CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", 
"CEN", "CEN", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", 
"IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", 
"CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", 
"CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "IPS", "IPS", 
"IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", 
"IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", 
"CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", 
"CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", 
"IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", 
"IPS"), test = c("Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test"), trial = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), Variables = c("Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", "Eye movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", "Hand movement time", 
"Hand movement time"), Eye_Mx = c(1.150583333, 1.273916667, 1.213083333, 
1.065166667, 1.2373, 1.19925, 0.93675, 0.950833333, 0.616916667, 
0.440416667, 0.598083333, 0.618583333, 0.693545455, 0.667583333, 
0.873666667, 0.51825, 1.220454545, 1.034583333, 0.874583333, 
1.015166667, 0.532222222, 0.714454545, 0.905583333, 0.898333333, 
0.641666667, 0.787666667, 0.609833333, 0.623583333, 0.69925, 
0.7188, 0.61725, 0.661166667, 1.349, 1.585416667, 1.0145, 1.201090909, 
0.810545455, 0.591090909, 1.1416, 0.697166667, 0.431166667, 0.804583333, 
0.289666667, 0.63875, 0.46825, 0.633, 0.418833333, 0.691166667, 
1.219125, 0.7033, 0.524666667, 0.724818182, 0.648583333, 0.639181818, 
0.596583333, 0.509416667, 0.576272727, 0.483222222, 0.388222222, 
0.647, 0.42575, 0.269818182, 0.488333333, 0.5903, 1.869083333, 
2.066181818, 2.124166667, 2.31525, 2.0943, 1.93625, 1.786916667, 
1.922583333, 1.470833333, 1.421454545, 1.519083333, 1.508833333, 
1.575909091, 1.5135, 1.8025, 1.541, 1.800454545, 1.888666667, 
1.85575, 2.201666667, 1.55725, 1.7781, 1.748, 1.767583333, 1.489333333, 
1.4259, 1.436916667, 1.5855, 1.535666667, 1.4013, 1.3855, 1.356666667, 
1.852888889, 2.463636364, 2.031, 2.195727273, 1.804454545, 1.709090909, 
2.1938, 1.97625, 1.256833333, 1.704363636, 1.418083333, 1.371166667, 
1.459166667, 1.46725, 1.183666667, 1.407, 2.348625, 1.8981, 1.973583333, 
1.746727273, 1.6805, 1.963, 1.68075, 1.872583333, 1.345636364, 
1.339222222, 1.311222222, 1.316833333, 1.215833333, 1.053636364, 
1.415916667, 1.2292), sd = c(0.948671172, 0.678775831, 0.820965004, 
0.771358286, 1.11350558, 0.598444974, 0.794668727, 0.824723627, 
0.481933503, 0.314103185, 0.469586754, 0.576648697, 0.629203681, 
0.528873667, 0.975212642, 0.406696922, 0.986302019, 0.821480975, 
0.776634401, 0.804389643, 0.52690957, 0.881839936, 0.881676756, 
0.842954149, 0.49820502, 0.551171205, 0.611370269, 0.630794947, 
0.605911653, 0.612136659, 0.504005614, 0.478993231, 0.896792758, 
1.545713396, 1.479810742, 1.481512366, 1.016337185, 0.827241616, 
1.987092303, 0.874371549, 0.557526165, 1.312183015, 0.163762763, 
1.081580084, 0.682258832, 0.99675364, 0.582176455, 1.069035235, 
1.352635886, 1.003522136, 0.705413397, 0.93395362, 0.764277848, 
0.989686599, 0.875251492, 0.582424316, 0.618786084, 0.971365119, 
0.4453251, 1.057255968, 0.710771044, 0.157439397, 0.584064339, 
0.966582301, 0.807429305, 0.578682092, 0.911954428, 1.146678771, 
0.977409848, 0.7173858, 0.692368328, 0.84760684, 0.426626052, 
0.392027133, 0.463031406, 0.346331904, 0.435984278, 0.625301164, 
0.733525794, 0.468399014, 0.911551574, 0.845252338, 0.560227896, 
1.191183013, 0.503701088, 0.686482249, 0.812501692, 0.649220856, 
0.448065201, 0.520082782, 0.465629478, 0.601450142, 0.498518229, 
0.432112652, 0.422273393, 0.374147354, 0.631002663, 1.659917846, 
1.024954525, 1.202822771, 0.652806306, 0.768222032, 1.742846509, 
0.782477781, 0.398411581, 0.98639944, 0.580826286, 0.781519247, 
0.683742619, 0.717473487, 0.26632937, 0.748351886, 1.884740371, 
0.875399141, 0.661320505, 0.703044393, 0.49535084, 0.954243365, 
0.645801986, 1.293963499, 0.649359573, 0.623769945, 0.256283426, 
0.8611224, 0.495113363, 0.158687285, 0.522609442, 0.635988959
), se = c(0.273857778, 0.195945704, 0.236992183, 0.222671957, 
0.352121382, 0.172756183, 0.229401102, 0.238077204, 0.139122219, 
0.090673779, 0.135558019, 0.16646414, 0.189712048, 0.152672677, 
0.281519641, 0.117403289, 0.297381248, 0.237141131, 0.22419504, 
0.232207288, 0.175636523, 0.265884745, 0.254518156, 0.243339902, 
0.143819401, 0.159109422, 0.176487395, 0.182094816, 0.174911628, 
0.193574608, 0.145493889, 0.138273435, 0.298930919, 0.446209023, 
0.467957245, 0.446692786, 0.306437191, 0.249422732, 0.62837376, 
0.252409325, 0.160943941, 0.378794609, 0.047274238, 0.312225276, 
0.19695116, 0.287737991, 0.168059866, 0.30860389, 0.478229004, 
0.317341563, 0.203635307, 0.281597612, 0.220628011, 0.298401737, 
0.252663342, 0.168131418, 0.186571024, 0.323788373, 0.1484417, 
0.305203509, 0.205181927, 0.047469764, 0.168604852, 0.305660162, 
0.233084763, 0.174479216, 0.263258567, 0.331017649, 0.309084133, 
0.207091442, 0.19986952, 0.244683019, 0.123156333, 0.118200628, 
0.133665654, 0.099977409, 0.131454206, 0.180508898, 0.211750657, 
0.135215148, 0.274843141, 0.244003332, 0.161723863, 0.343864917, 
0.178085227, 0.217084748, 0.244978478, 0.187413918, 0.129345282, 
0.164464616, 0.134415652, 0.173623701, 0.143909817, 0.136646019, 
0.121899828, 0.108007038, 0.210334221, 0.500484062, 0.32411908, 
0.362664711, 0.196828507, 0.231627658, 0.551136458, 0.225881879, 
0.115011517, 0.297410621, 0.167670106, 0.225605174, 0.197379493, 
0.207116755, 0.076882667, 0.216030581, 0.666356349, 0.276825515, 
0.190906786, 0.21197586, 0.14299547, 0.2877152, 0.186426975, 
0.373535087, 0.195789278, 0.207923315, 0.085427809, 0.248584625, 
0.142926917, 0.047846017, 0.150864351, 0.201117368), ci = c(0.602756906, 
0.431273588, 0.521616278, 0.490097673, 0.796553907, 0.380233796, 
0.504908421, 0.524004393, 0.306205939, 0.199571642, 0.298361189, 
0.366385102, 0.422704785, 0.336030297, 0.619620551, 0.258402896, 
0.662606712, 0.52194411, 0.493449956, 0.511084796, 0.405018549, 
0.59242813, 0.560190685, 0.535587514, 0.316544368, 0.350197476, 
0.388446137, 0.400787988, 0.384977898, 0.437896186, 0.320229889, 
0.304337779, 0.689335936, 0.982099437, 1.058592834, 0.99529355, 
0.682784611, 0.555748479, 1.421480202, 0.555549178, 0.354235225, 
0.833721312, 0.104049895, 0.6872032, 0.433486581, 0.633307048, 
0.369897272, 0.679232583, 1.1308319, 0.71787649, 0.448198289, 
0.627438579, 0.485598977, 0.664880504, 0.556108267, 0.370054755, 
0.415706148, 0.746657327, 0.342307174, 0.671748394, 0.451602376, 
0.105769226, 0.371096776, 0.691451324, 0.513016105, 0.388763919, 
0.5794282, 0.728564932, 0.699196885, 0.455805192, 0.439909848, 
0.538543693, 0.271065261, 0.263367411, 0.29419612, 0.220048794, 
0.292898224, 0.397297405, 0.466060055, 0.297606535, 0.61238868, 
0.537047714, 0.355951823, 0.756841578, 0.421104648, 0.491079817, 
0.545846064, 0.412495252, 0.284687047, 0.37204481, 0.295846856, 
0.382143188, 0.316743371, 0.30911477, 0.268299713, 0.237721887, 
0.485031584, 1.115147982, 0.733208298, 0.808067333, 0.438561244, 
0.516098584, 1.246757287, 0.497162663, 0.253138642, 0.66267216, 
0.369039416, 0.49655364, 0.434429334, 0.455860905, 0.169217609, 
0.475480104, 1.575682382, 0.626222821, 0.420183003, 0.47231165, 
0.314730908, 0.641069416, 0.410323006, 0.822145184, 0.436245697, 
0.479472024, 0.19699688, 0.54713107, 0.314580023, 0.106607569, 
0.332050198, 0.454959094)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -128L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Condition = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), test = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), trial = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Variables = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Eye_Mx = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), sd = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), se = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), ci = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

And here's my `ggplot` codes:

```
p <- ggplot(data10, aes(x = trial, y = Eye_Mx)) + 
   geom_line(aes(color = Variables, linetype = Variables), lwd=1.2) + 
   scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred", "steelblue")) + facet_grid(Condition ~ Group)+ theme_bw() + xlab("Trial Pre- / Post-test") + ylab("Hand and Eye Movement time (s)") +
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,16), breaks = seq(1,16,1)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10,face="bold", angle = 90),#, angle = 10, hjust = .5, vjust = .5),
                                                                      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
                                                                      axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 1.8, size = 16),
                                                                      axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5, size = 16),
                                                                      axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +  theme(legend.position="top")+
   geom_vline(xintercept=8.5, linetype="dashed", color = "black", size=1.5) 
 
 p + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Variables:")) + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14),legend.title=element_text(size=14) ) +
   theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=12)) + annotate("segment", x = 11, xend = 9, y = 4, yend = 3, colour = "black", size=1, alpha=0.9, arrow=arrow())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an additional dataframe (e.g. `arrowdf`) which includes the `Condition` and `Group` that you would like to annotate. I also grouped all of your `theme()` arguments so that they are more clear.

```
arrowdf <- tibble(Condition = "CEN", Group = "Remembered")

ggplot(data10, aes(x = trial, y = Eye_Mx)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Variables, linetype = Variables), lwd=1.2) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred", "steelblue")) + 
  facet_grid(Condition ~ Group)+ 
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab("Trial Pre- / Post-test") + 
  ylab("Hand and Eye Movement time (s)") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,16), breaks = seq(1,16,1)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10,face="bold", angle = 90),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 1.8, size = 16),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5, size = 16),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=14),
        legend.title=element_text(size=14),
        strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=12),
        legend.position="top")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=8.5, linetype="dashed", color = "black", size=1.5) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Variables:")) + 
  geom_segment(data = arrowdf, 
               aes(x = 11, xend = 9, y = 4, yend = 3), 
               colour = "black", size = 1, alpha=0.9, arrow = arrow())
```

[image: arrow in one facet]

Comment: How do I follow the arrow with a text